# Python: how do I make these asynchronous methods communicate?

Tags: python, cherrypy, python-asyncio, aiohttp

I started doing asynchronous code and I still don't fully understand it.

I wrote a program that sets up a CherryPy web server, and intentionally delays the return of a GET request.
Then I used the *aiohttp* module to make an asynchronous request.

**What I did manage to do:**
Run some printing loop while waiting for the response
**What I WANT to do effectively:**
Make the loop run ONLY until I get the response (Right now it just continues running)

That's my code:

```
import cherrypy
import time
import threading
import asyncio
import aiohttp


# The Web App
class CherryApp:
    @cherrypy.expose
    def index(self):
        time.sleep(5)
        return open('views/index.html')


async def get_page(url):
    session = aiohttp.ClientSession()
    resp = await session.get(url)
    return resp

async def waiter():

    # I want to break this loop when I get a response
    while True:
        print("Waiting for response")
        await asyncio.sleep(1)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Start the server
    server = threading.Thread(target=cherrypy.quickstart, args=[CherryApp()])
    server.start()

    # Run the async methods
    event_loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    tasks = [get_page('http://127.0.0.1:8080/'), waiter()]

    # Obviously, the 'waiter()' method never completes, so this just runs forever
    event_loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.wait(tasks))
```

So, how do I make async functions "aware" of each other?

Comment: How about putting them in a queue, and once each of the functions return it will end the running of the program ? I didn't quite understand what are you aiming for, try to make it more abstract by not being so specific, are you trying to signal a thread to die from another thread ? Are you waiting for a function to exit ?

Comment: You could create a class that contains your two coroutines then you can set and share the state via a variable. In the waiting coroutine you then just add an if check.

Comment: If you're ready to use asyncio, why not use aiohttp instead of CherryPy?

Comment: @SylvainHellegouarch What does it have to do with the question? It's not about how I implement a web server...

Comment: Well, it matters in the sense that CP and asyncio are quite orthogonal in their behavior, you'd get a smoother experience would you use CP+threads or aiohttp+asyncio. You are making your life more complicated here.

Answer (score 0):

Use a variable, for example, a global:

```
done = False

async def get_page(url):
    global done
    session = aiohttp.ClientSession()
    resp = await session.get(url)
    done = True
    return resp

async def waiter():
    while not done:
        print("Waiting for response")
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
    print("done!")
```